# Modifying a json file

Tags: python, json

I am writing a program which updates api keys as they timeout, so I have a json file which tracks all the api keys and whether or not they're on cooldown, but I am struggling with a way to update the "cooldown" property of the api key property without just editing the data contained in the api key property.

Thanks in advance for the help

```
import json
import io
import time
import re


def json_Data_Pull():
    file = open('api_Key.json', 'r')
    data = json.load(file)

    return data

#Each api key is assigned a number and when this function is called the specific
#number given in parameters is called, if that number isn't on cooldown, it will
#be returned, otherwise the function will at +1 to that and find another key
def new_Key_Pull(number):
    data = json_Data_Pull()
    arr = []
    try:
        loads = json.loads(data)
        js = json.dumps(loads['api' + number])
        cooldown = re.search(r'("cooldown": "(.*?)")', js, )
        final = re.sub(r'"cooldown": "|"', '' , cooldown.group())
        arr.insert(1, final)
        api = re.search(r'("api(.*)": "(.*?)"})', js, )
        final2 = re.sub(r'"api(.*)": "|"|}', '', api.group())
        arr.insert(2, final2)

        return arr
    except(TypeError):
        pass

#This function sets the current state of an API key to false, and then waits for 62 seconds
#and resetts it to true in order to create a cooldown on each key so that api timeouts
#don't occurr
def cooldown_Key(api):
    loads = json.loads(json_Data_Pull())
    jsd = json.dump(loads)
```

Json File:

```
"""{
  "api1":{
  "api1": "Num 1",
  "cooldown": "False"
  },
  "api2":{
  "api2": "Num 2",
  "cooldown": "False"
  },
  "api3":{
  "api3": "Num 3",
  "cooldown": "True"
  }
  } """
```

Comment: You can treat JSON as if it were a dictionary.

Comment: I understand that part, but I am not entirely sure how I would go about pulling the proper api key, and then changing the cool down value under it. Is there a way to call a section and modify the values inside said section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = """{
  "api1":{
  "api1": "Num 1",
  "cooldown": "False"
  },
  "api2":{
  "api2": "Num 2",
  "cooldown": "False"
  },
  "api3":{
  "api3": "Num 3",
  "cooldown": "True"
  }
  } """

data = json.loads(data)

# example: modify "api1" cooldown to "True"
data["api1"]["cooldown"] = "True"
print(data)
```

Comment: I think you mean `True` and not `"True"`. Big difference.

Comment: That makes sense, but I added it and now I am receiving an different issue, ValueError: Extra data: line1 column 3 - line 15 column 1 (char 2 - 192)

Comment: @AntonvBR Thanks for pointing that out. I was aware of that but followed OP's version. He has False/True as strings rather than bools.

Comment: @SageHopkins Ok. That is hard to solve without having full code. Might not be related and a different issue. Where exactly do you get that error? And if you print out the modified JSON: Do you get a correct result or not?

Comment: No longer returning that error, I fixed it but I am having trouble with I think the file containing json data, for some reason everytime my func for getting data is called everything after that returns none

Comment: @SageHopkins Ok. Sorry to hear that. I suggest you post this as a different question with the relevant parts of code.